# How to upgrade BasicTeX?

Tags: mac, mactex

Is there a quick and simple way to reinstall all the packages I downloaded for BasicTeX 2013 with Tex Live Manager into version 2014? 
Should I just copy the folders – which? – from the old distribution?

**Update:** This question is different from [BasicTeX - how to identify packages that need to be added after an upgrade](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87853/basictex-how-to-identify-packages-that-need-to-be-added-after-an-upgrade) in that I’m not looking to generate a list of packages to install manually, but to automate the whole process.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do exactly or how you are proposing to do it but I suspect the answer to your second/third questions is 'No'.

Comment: On Linux, `tlmgr info --only-installed | sed 's/^i \(.*\):.*$/\1/'` will give you the list of installed things. So you could then use that to install the corresponding stuff in TL 2014.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to (automatically): 1) Query your old installation for packages added above and beyond the BasicTeX standard set then 2) have the new installation download and install all of these packages. Is that right?

Comment: @JosephWright, yes, that would be swell. Actually, I believe that option should be offered automatically when upgrading.

Comment: @Crissov: did you find an easy way to do it in the meantime? I'm having the same question.

Comment: @mostlyharmless No, not in 2015.nor 2016.

Comment: hm, I just tried with the `Tex Live Utility` installed with `BasicTeX 2015`and installed upgrades for all packages which seemed to work (or am I missing something?).